# Link destination to origin on dashboard

Tags: arcgis-pro, origin-destination, dashboard

How do I have it set on an ArcGIS Pro dashboard that if I click on a polygon (destination) that it will display the origins that lead to it?  (They have a matching table field).  Not looking for lines but for when clicking on the said destination, all the origins that lead to it will appear also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what software are you using? please add a tag for it

Comment: I am using ArcGis PRo

Comment: I am trying to click on an a destination, (business district) and have all the origins that share the same code on a second shp display

Comment: Thanks, Ian, editted